# Why didn't Greg House just amputate his leg?

Tags: plot-explanation, house

There's an episode where Dr. House says that he should have amputated his leg. So why doesn't he?

Comment: Do you mean "why didn't he amputate it *at the time*", or "why hasn't he amputated it since then"? Paulie_D has answered the former but I suspect you may actually be asking the latter.

Comment: Not sure why there's so many downvotes on this one... House is a difficult character to read, ***especially*** when it comes to his leg. Even though he's made comments about wishing he would have amputated his leg, that only happened in later seasons *after* he had made personal connections with a couple women (i.e., after he went into rehab). 99% of the time though House valued his skills as a doctor above all else and believed that being in pain helped him stay detached from the patients which helped his deductive reasoning. This question yields an answer that's *far* from obvious. +1.

Comment: Thank you Charles. Yes, I was asking why has he amputated his leg since then.

Answer (score 6):

### Because he wanted to save his leg.

> House: You asked me how I'd hurt my leg. I had a blood clot, and the muscle was dying. And I had all these doctors telling me I should amputate, and I said no, and they did this... very risky operation. I almost died.
>
> Hanna: (shivering) But you saved your leg.
>
> House: I wish I hadn't.

Certainly, **with the benefit of hindsight** House wishes that he had agreed to the amputation but at the time he wasn't to know the full ramifications of the drastic procedure he did undergo and the effects it would have on him as a person.

> House: They cut out a chunk of muscle about the size of my fist, and they left me with this, mutilated, useless thing. I'm in pain... Every day. **It changed me. Made me a harder person, a worse person. And now... Now I'm alone**. You don't want to be like me. You’ve got a husband who loves you. You have friends. You can start a family. You have a life. And this... This is just a leg.

Comment: He may say after all this he wishes he didn't, but it was still a better option. It's more of his bitterness than objectivity. One can think "no leg = no pain" but it's *not* true.